# Gulp-sass and Browser Sync

Tags: gulp, jekyll, browser-sync, gulp-sass

I am not sure if the problem is browser-sync but that would be my best bet. My problem is I am using gulp to automate my workflow for the first time. And when I "gulp things" it runs it opens a new webpage with my project like it should, but when I change anything in my SASS file it does not updates it, even if I hit the refresh key, the only way for me to refresh it is to re-gulp everything.

I have all the dependecies updated. I am using Jekyll also. And some other gulp-plugins.

Heres my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp               = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    sass                   = require('gulp-sass'),
    prefix                = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss        = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    jshint                = require('gulp-jshint'),
    concat              = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename      = require('gulp-rename'),
    cp          = require('child_process'),
    jade        = require('gulp-jade'),
    bourbon     = require('bourbon').includePaths;

var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};


/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    var pl = process.platform === "win32" ? "jekyll.bat" : "jekyll";
    return cp.spawn(pl, ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});


/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});


/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'js', 'jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        },
        notify: false
    });
});


/**
 * Compile files from _scss into both _site/css (for live injecting) and site (for future jekyll builds)
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('assets/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: [bourbon],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});


/**
 * Compile Jade
 */
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src('_jadefiles/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_includes'));
});


/*
** JS Task
*/
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/js/common.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('common.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/js'));
});


/**
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Watch html/md files, run jekyll & reload BrowserSync
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('assets/js/**/*.js', ['js']).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('assets/css/**', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['*.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_posts/*', '_includes/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
    gulp.watch('_jadefiles/*.jade', ['jade']);
});


/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will compile the sass,
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync & watch files.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

where are your sass files?

the bit at the bottom - 'watch' is probably where the problem is.

I think you need to add where your sass folder is. Assuming it is _sass then maybe adding it to the 3rd gulp.watch line like this would work.

`gulp.watch(['*.html','_sass/*', '_layouts/*.html', '_posts/*', '_includes/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);`

Comment: Thanks, going to try it out, now. Tell you if it works later.

Comment: It did work, thank you so much. I have been on this for 2 days now. I am still new to gulp.

Answer (score 1):

This code sets up your watches. But only the js changes are set to notify browser sync:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('assets/js/**/*.js', ['js']).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('assets/css/**', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['*.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_posts/*', '_includes/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
    gulp.watch('_jadefiles/*.jade', ['jade']);
});
```

Tell gulp watch to notify browser sync on sass change:

```
gulp.watch('assets/css/**/*.sass', ['sass']).on("change", browserSync.reload);
```

But really you want to run 'sass' on sass changes, and then notify browserSync on css changes:

```
gulp.watch('assets/css/**/*.css').on("change", browserSync.reload);
gulp.watch('assets/css/**/*.sass', ['sass'])
```

Comment: For Jekyll, I think when the watch sees a change it needs to do jekyll-rebuild - not reload the browser. If you reload the browser without a rebuild then it isn't going to pickup the change in the site folder. I think the js.on-change-sync bit is to reload the browser after browser-sync injects its bit of magic. I could be very wrong, but that is my understanding.

Comment: Totally possible. I know nothing of the jekyll. If this was straight js/html/sass, then this would answer would be one of the possible solutions. No clue what voodoo the jekyll wants. :-D